# Material UI - File Upload -

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, material-ui

[image]

With the file upload on Material UI -- can I specify the file-types it can accept - is it just adding params like "accept" into the textField?

what is I wanted to upload more than one file?  create these TextField file types on the fly - for redux forms to register?

https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/fieldarrays/

I am thinking of creating a drag and drop interface that hides these fields - but populates them as the user drags/uploads the file to it - but how to programmatically change the upload field - unless modifying the input.value?

this is what my current file Upload field looks like -- I've added a paperclip attachment icon at the right - so its a bit like the date picker with the calendar icon - or render a little thumbnail of the current stored image

or is it part of the InputProps for this --  "accept": "image/png, image/jpeg"

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';

import AttachFileIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AttachFile';

const renderFileUpload = ({input, rows, multiline, label, required, type, placeholder, fieldRef, onClick, disabled, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => {
  let previewUrl = "";

  if(input.value && input.value.length > 0){
    if(typeof input.value === "string"){
      previewUrl = input.value;
    }
    if(typeof input.value === "object"){
      //previewUrl = input.value[0].name;
    }
  }
  console.log("previewUrl", previewUrl);

  delete input.value;
  
  return (
  <FormControl component="fieldset" fullWidth={true}>    
    <TextField
      className="fileUpload"
      label={required ? label + " *": label}
      type={type}
      error={touched && (error && error.length > 0 ? true : false)}
      helperText={touched &&
        ((error && error.length > 0 ? error : null) || 
        (warning && warning.length > 0 ? warning : null))
      }
      InputLabelProps={{shrink: true}}
      disabled={disabled}
      {...input}
    />
    <div className="previewIcon">
      {previewUrl && previewUrl.length > 0 ?
        (
          <img src={previewUrl} />
        ):
        (
          <AttachFileIcon />
        )
      }
    </div>
  </FormControl>
)}

export default renderFileUpload;
```

Comment: https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/file-upload-in-material-ui/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file
https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: I've created a fieldArray here - https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-http-5jz71?file=/src/GenericForm/GenericForm.scss

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Unique_file_type_specifiers

Comment: adding inputProps={{"accept":"image/jpeg", "multiple": true}}  -- will start to give you control of image types and multiple files